# Cocos2d 3.0 Set Portrait orientation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Already added below code in AppDelegate.m but still not working in portrait.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Here is Xcode summary page:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got solution. We can set orientation in setupCocos2dWithOptions.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setupCocos2dWithOptions:@{
        CCSetupShowDebugStats: @(YES),
        CCSetupScreenOrientation: CCScreenOrientationPortrait,
    }];

    return YES;
}
```